# Cannot remove read only file system

Tags: rm

I have some videos recorded using gopro. The videos are in the SD card. Now i want to delete them. But rm gives me this command. How do I delete them?

```
rm: cannot remove 'GOPR0002.JPG': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove 'GOPR0008.JPG': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove 'GOPR0014.JPG': Read-only file system
```

Comment: The SD card is mounted in read only and will have to be remounted in Read Write to be able to delete items from it.  You haven't given a lot of detail as to what you are trying to do, so this is only guessing.  Run the `mount` command and see if you can see the mount for that SD card then try running `sudo mount -o remount,rw <mount point>` then you should be able to delete the files.

Comment: Do you have the write-protect switch on the SD card in the r/w position?